# Code is too slow to categorise and copy a mere 250 rows

Tags: performance, vba, excel, optimization

I have implemented the changes suggested and now have a worksheet that is taking 3 times as long as it did.  Also it no longer forms my nice neat 4 segmented worksheet but is jumbled and chaotic. Help please.

```
 Private Sub ReportMakeReady_Click()

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

 Unload Me
 Dim FRow As Long
 Dim LRow As Long
 Dim ColAPLast1 As Long
 Dim ColAPLast2 As Long
 Dim APValues As Variant
 Dim MRValues As Variant
 Dim AP As Worksheet
 Dim MR As Worksheet

 Set AP = Worksheets("apartments")
 Set MR = Worksheets("Make Ready")

 Dim CRented As Long, CRemodel As Long, CAdmin As Long, CRNMI As Long, CStatus As Long, CUnit As Long
 Dim CTurnNotes As Long, CUnitNotes As Long, CFinal As Long, CCabinets As Long, CFridge As Long, CRange As Long
 Dim CAC As Long, CTub As Long, CCLean As Long, CPaint As Long, CVynal As Long, CUporDown As Long, CITV As Long
 Dim CCarpet As Long, CMaint As Long, CMoveIn As Long, CFloorPlan As Long, CMoveOutRemodel As Long, CTurn As Long

 Dim MRentedMain As Long, MRented1Bed As Long, MRented2Bed As Long
 Dim MAvailMain As Long, MAvail1Bed As Long, MAvail2Bed As Long
 Dim MNotAvailMain As Long, MNotAvail1Bed As Long, MNotAvail2Bed As Long
 Dim MNoticeMain As Long, MNotice1Bed As Long, MNotice2Bed As Long, MEndLine As Long

 Dim MUnit As Long, MFloorPlan As Long, MUporDown As Long, MRemodel As Long
 Dim MMoveOutRemodel As Long, MMoveIn As Long, MStatus As Long, MMaint As Long
 Dim MCarpet As Long, MVynal As Long, MPaint As Long, MClean As Long, MAC As Long, MFridge As Long
 Dim MRange As Long, MTub As Long, MUnitNotes As Long, MTurnNotes As Long, MFinal As Long, MCabinets As Long

        With Worksheets("apartments")
            ColAPLast1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, ColAPLast1))
                CRented = .Find("Occupied").Column
                CRNMI = .Find("RNMI").Column
                CAdmin = .Find("Admin").Column
                CTurn = .Find("Turned").Column
                CITV = .Find("ITV").Column
                CFloorPlan = .Find("Floor Plan").Column
                CUnit = .Find("Apartment").Column
                CUporDown = .Find("Up or Down").Column
                CRemodel = .Find("Remodel").Column
                CMoveOutRemodel = .Find("MO / Remodel").Column
                CMoveIn = .Find("Move In").Column
                CStatus = .Find("Status").Column
                CMaint = .Find("Maintenance").Column
                CCarpet = .Find("Carpet").Column
                CVynal = .Find("Linoleum").Column
                CPaint = .Find("Painted").Column
                CCLean = .Find("Clean").Column
                CAC = .Find("AC").Column
                CFridge = .Find("Fridge").Column
                CRange = .Find("Range").Column
                CTub = .Find("Tub").Column
                CCabinets = .Find("Cabinets").Column
                CUnitNotes = .Find("Unit Notes").Column
                CFinal = .Find("Final Inspec").Column
                CTurnNotes = .Find("Turn Notes").Column
            End With
        End With

        With Worksheets("Make Ready")
            ColAPLast2 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, ColAPLast2))
                MUnit = .Find("Unit").Column
                MFloorPlan = .Find("Floor").Column
                MUporDown = .Find("UpDown").Column
                MRemodel = .Find("Remodel").Column
                MMoveOutRemodel = .Find("Mo/Re Date").Column
                MMoveIn = .Find("Move in").Column
                MStatus = .Find("Status").Column
                MMaint = .Find("Maint").Column
                MCarpet = .Find("Carpet").Column
                MVynal = .Find("Vynal").Column
                MPaint = .Find("Paint").Column
                MClean = .Find("Clean").Column
                MAC = .Find("AC").Column
                MFridge = .Find("Fridge").Column
                MRange = .Find("Range").Column
                MTub = .Find("Tub").Column
                MCabinets = .Find("Cabinets").Column
                MUnitNotes = .Find("Unit Notes").Column
                MFinal = .Find("Final").Column
                MTurnNotes = .Find("Turn Notes").Column
            End With
        End With

        With MR.Range("A1:A250")
            MRentedMain = .Find("RentedMain").Row
            MRented1Bed = .Find("Rented1Bed").Row
            MRented2Bed = .Find("Rented2Bed").Row
            MAvailMain = .Find("AvailableMain").Row
            MAvail1Bed = .Find("Available1Bed").Row
            MAvail2Bed = .Find("Available2Bed").Row
            MNotAvailMain = .Find("NotAvailableMain").Row
            MNotAvail1Bed = .Find("NotAvailable1Bed").Row
            MNotAvail2Bed = .Find("NotAvailable2Bed").Row
            MNoticeMain = .Find("NoticeMain").Row
            MNotice1Bed = .Find("Notice1Bed").Row
            MNotice2Bed = .Find("Notice2Bed").Row
            MEndLine = .Find("EndLine").Row
        End With

        With Worksheets("apartments")
            APValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(250, ColAPLast1)).Value
        End With

        With Worksheets("Make Ready")
            MRValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(250, ColAPLast2)).Value
        End With

For FRow = 2 To 250

    If APValues(FRow, CAdmin) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRNMI) = "" And APValues(FRow, CITV) = "" _
        And APValues(FRow, CTurn) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRented) = "" Then
            If APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1 W/D" Or APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1" Then
                LRow = ((MNotAvail2Bed - MNotAvail1Bed) - 2) + MNotAvail1Bed
                MR.Cells(MNotAvail2Bed, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            Else: APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "2x1"
                LRow = ((MNoticeMain - MNotAvail2Bed) - 2) + MNotAvail2Bed
                MR.Cells(MNoticeMain, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
    ElseIf APValues(FRow, CAdmin) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRNMI) = "" And APValues(FRow, CITV) = "" _
        And APValues(FRow, CTurn) = "X" And APValues(FRow, CRented) = "" Then
            If APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1 W/D" Or APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1" Then
                LRow = ((MAvail2Bed - MAvail1Bed) - 2) + MAvail1Bed
                MR.Cells(MAvail2Bed, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            Else: APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "2x1"
                LRow = ((MNotAvailMain - MAvail2Bed) - 2) + MAvail2Bed
                MR.Cells(MNotAvailMain, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
    ElseIf APValues(FRow, CAdmin) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRNMI) = "" And APValues(FRow, CITV) = "X" _
        And APValues(FRow, CTurn) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRented) = "" Then
            If APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1 W/D" Or APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1" Then
                LRow = ((MNotice2Bed - MNotice1Bed) - 2) + MNotice1Bed
                MR.Cells(MNotice2Bed, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            Else: APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "2x1"
                LRow = ((MEndLine - MNotice2Bed) - 2) + MNotice2Bed
                MR.Cells(MEndLine, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
    ElseIf APValues(FRow, CAdmin) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRNMI) = "X" And APValues(FRow, CITV) = "" _
        And APValues(FRow, CTurn) = "" And APValues(FRow, CRented) = "" Then
            If APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1 W/D" Or APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1" Then
                LRow = ((MRented2Bed - MRented1Bed) - 2) + MRented1Bed
                MR.Cells(MRented2Bed, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            Else: APValues(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "2x1"
                LRow = ((MAvailMain - MRented2Bed) - 2) + MRented2Bed
                MR.Cells(MAvailMain, 1).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
    End If

        If LRow = 0 Then
        Else
            MR.Cells(LRow, MUnit).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CUnit).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MFloorPlan).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MUporDown).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CUporDown).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MRemodel).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CRemodel).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MMoveOutRemodel).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CMoveOutRemodel).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MMoveIn).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CMoveIn).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MStatus).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CStatus).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MMaint).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CMaint).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MCarpet).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CCarpet).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MVynal).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CVynal).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MPaint).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CPaint).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MClean).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CCLean).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MAC).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CAC).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MFridge).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CFridge).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MRange).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CRange).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MTub).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CTub).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MCabinets).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CCabinets).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MUnitNotes).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CUnitNotes).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MFinal).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CFinal).Value
            MR.Cells(LRow, MTurnNotes).Value = AP.Cells(FRow, CTurnNotes).Value
            LRow = 0
        End If

Next FRow

Worksheets("Make Ready").Activate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: I know I'm not willing to read this code to figure out what's wrong.  Does Visual Studio not have breakpoints?

Comment: Are the columns discontiguous? Do you really need to spec them out individually, rather than as an array?

Comment: Can you try narrowing down your problem to a particular chunk of code, instead of putting your entire program here?  That will make it easier for people to help you out.

Comment: To narrow it down to a particular chunk of code, use timers and find out which parts of the code are taking a long time to run.

Comment: You're repeating those column find() calls over and over: I would create a scripting dictionary for each sheet to map column headers to row numbers and populate them at the start of the Sub. Even just moving those two existing blocks out of the loop to the top of the code will help...

Comment: The reason each location is individually addressed is that as the program goes along the column locations can change - meaning hard addresses can't be used, it must be done dynamically.   I'm unsure how to cut the size down as this is just a small snippet of the program that is slowing thing down, it is simply the click event for a command button on a userform.

Comment: EIther the `With Worksheets("apartments").Range("A1:ZA1")` is over-simplified, either you can do it once out of the main loop. There's no way columns will change during execution.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use '.Find()' to be dynamic. Read the whole sheet to an array and loop through the column headers until you find what you are looking for.

Comment: xum59, I have already tried that and it had little effect. I have put them before, after and in the middle of the loop and there is no measurable time difference.  I misspoke by saying column location can change.  It is that data requirement get added and subtracted continuously and the headers are shuffled around.

Comment: Kyle, if you could elaborate some.  I have never been successful loading a array with a sheet and been able to sift through the data inside it.  It is definitely a weak point for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion 1**

Take the code to find the columns in worksheets "apartments" and "Make Ready" outside the main loop.  That is 39 finds that you perform 249 times when you could have performed them once.

**Suggestion 2**

Nest your Ifs.

For example, for the first If you test `AP.Cells(FRow, CRented) = "" And AP.Cells(FRow, CRNMI) = "X" And AP.Cells(FRow, CAdmin) = "" And AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1"`.  For the second If you repeat the first three tests with a different fourth test.  For the third If you repeat the first three tests again with a third fourth test.

The following would save a lot of repeated tests:

```
If AP.Cells(FRow, CRented) = "" And AP.Cells(FRow, CRNMI) = "X" And _
   AP.Cells(FRow, CAdmin) = ""
  If AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1" Then
    ...
  ElseIf AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1 W/D"
    ...
  ElseIf AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "2x1"
    ...
  ElseIf AP.Cells(FRow, CFloorPlan) = "1x1"
ElseIf ...
```

The fourth If repeats two of the first three tests so you could further reduce the number of tests with another level of nesting.  However, you are possibly gaining improved speed by reducing clarity.  Leave this suggestion until you have tried some of the others since they may already have given you all the improved speed you want.

**Suggestion 3**

When you work on row 1 of worksheets "apartments" and "Make Ready" you use `Range("A1:ZA1")`.  Do you really have that many columns?  Consider:

```
With Worksheets("apartments")
  ColAPLast = .Cells(1,Columns.Count).Emd(xlToLeft).Column

  With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, ColAPLast)
    CUnit = .Find("Apartment").Column
  ...
```

**Suggestion 4**

I need you to know the final column of worksheets “apartment” because I want you to load it into memory.

Consider:

```
Dim APValues as Variant

APValues = AP.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(250,ColAPLast)).Value

If APValues(FRow, CRented) ...
```

The second statement loads the entire range of interest from worksheet "apartments" into variant APValues as a two dimensional array.  The third statement shows the syntax for accessing the value of a cell in memory is similar to that for accessing the values from the worksheet.  The difference is that accessing the value from memory is very much faster than accessing it from the worksheet.

You could do something similar when building the new row for worksheet “Make Ready” but that would be more complicated.  Try these suggestions and see what improvement in speed they give you.

**Suggestion 5**

`Integer` declares a 16-bit variable which requires special processing on a 32 or 64-bit computer.  Replace all you `Integer`s with `Long`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very incomplete example of how you'd use dictionaries to map the column headers and remove the need for having tons of variables to track their positions:

```
Private Sub ReportMakeReady_Click()

Unload Me

Dim FRow As Long '<<<< Long is always preferable to Integer...
Dim LRow As Long
Dim AP As Worksheet
Dim MR As Worksheet
Dim dAP As Object, dMR As Object, rwAP As Range, rwMR As Range

Set AP = Worksheets("apartments")
Set MR = Worksheets("Make Ready")

Set dAP = ColumnMap(AP.Range("A1:ZA1"))
Set dMR = ColumnMap(MR.Range("A1:ZA1"))

For FRow = 2 To 250

    Set rwAP = AP.Rows(FRow)

         '.............
         'all of your if tests here...
         '.............

         If LRow <> 0 Then

            Set rwMR = MR.Rows(LRow)

            MR.Cells(dMR("Unit")).Value = rw.Cells(dAP("Apartment")).Value
            MR.Cells(dMR("Floor")).Value = rw.Cells(dAP("Floor Plan")).Value
            MR.Cells(dMR("UpDown")).Value = rw.Cells(dAP("Up or Down")).Value
            '...etc
            LRow = 0
        End If

Next FRow


End Sub

'Get a scripting dictionary which maps headers to column  number
'Note: will error if header is duplicated...
Function ColumnMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim rv As Object, c As Range, v
    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then rv.Add v, c.Column
    Next c
    Set ColumnMap = rv
End Function
```

Even easier to manage if you use a two-column table of "source" and "destination" column headers and use that to drive the data transfer...